# Add semicolon at the end of file when missing

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, awk

I get file whith a variable number of semicolons to separate my data.
8 mandatory columns with 7 semicolons to separate
2 non mandatory columns (linked, both exist or not), if exist, 9 semicolons in the file (what i need).

My asking is test all lines in file, test if 7 semicolons then add 2 semicolons at the end. If 9 semicolons then do nothing.

```
07/15/19 02:58:40 PM;toto2_UBD_FD_GPRS_GLBL_EXCP;TABLE;DATA;COMPLETE;BASE_TEST_DSA;0;0
07/15/19 02:58:40 PM;toto_UBD_FD_GPRS_GLBL_EXCP;TABLE;DATA;COMPLETE;BASE_TEST_DSA;37484032;253118
07/15/19 02:55:59 PM;UBD_FD_GPRS_GLBL_EXCP;TABLE;DATA;COMPLETE;BASE_TEST_DSA;37484032;253118
07/15/19 02:55:59 PM;UBV_FD_GSM_GLBL_EXCP;TABLE;DATA;COMPLETE;BASE_TEST_DSA;0;0
07/15/19 02:55:59 PM;UBV_FD_GSM_GLBL_EXCP;TABLE;DATA;COMPLETE;BASE_TEST_DSA;0;0;E1234;LIB1234
```

I imagine something like :

```
    while read line; do

        if [[ `awk -F ";" ' { print NF-1 }'` = "7" ]]; then

        sed '/;$/!s/$/;;/' $line

        fi
    done < TEST_FILE2.txt > TEST_FILE3.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed/awk processes a text file line by line, therefore you don't have to `read line` and pass the line to awk or/and sed.

Give this a try:

```
awk -F';' 'NF==8{$0=$0 ";;"}7' file
```

Comment: This could use some additional explanation. The action (inside `{}`) is utilizing `awk`'s feature that a bare list of strings is concatenated together. The final `7` is a non-zero condition with no action associated. It could be any non-zero expression; `1` is more typical. The default action in `awk` when none is specified is `{print}`.